# How to solve "No module named 'pattern.text'"

Tags: python, python-3.x

I imported the pattern package successfully on python 3. However, when I tried to do "from pattern.en import spelling", it didn't work.

Then I found someone says "from pattern.text.en import spelling" works for him so I tried and failed again.

```
from pattern.en import spelling
from pattern.text.en import spelling
```

The error messages say "No module named 'pattern.en'" and "No module named 'pattern.text'".

I using python 3.6 on windows and have not idea how to solve it.

========================================================================
update

I tried

```
print(dir(pattern))
```

and got

`['__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__']`

I still have no idea why it doesn't have the attributes I need

Comment: `pattern` is not a built-in library in Python. Have you installed it?

Comment: @chris yes I do install `pattern` and it works when I call `import pattern`, but it just not works when I try to call `from pattern.en import spelling`

Comment: Hm, do you have a file named `pattern.py` in your working directory? If so, `import` will load that rather than the pip-installed library, so you need to rename the file. If not, please update your question with the results from `import pattern; print(dir(pattern))`

Comment: I don't have that. So I tried `print(dir(pattern))` and got `['__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__']`, but I still not understand why this happened

Comment: what does `print(pattern.__file__)` print?

Comment: I got a path `'C:\\Users\\asus\\pattern\\__init__.py'`